# Eclipse compiler setting to catch == on String

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to configure eclipse to tag an == comparison on String objects as Errors? 
I just want a way to prevent developers from using == to compare strings accidentally or unknowingly.
I searched through eclipse and could not find anything. Any ideas.

Comment: *"to prevent developers from [...]"* -- as this sounds like it's for a whole team, just to be sure: you know about standalone tools such as Sonar? Why rely on some IDE setting while tools like Sonar can do so much more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing built into Eclipse that you can enable to do this check, afaik. But, you can incorporate a third party static analysis tool to do it for you. FindBugs does have a rule to check for exactly what you've described, and can be incorporated into Eclipse via plugin.

- [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)
- [FindBugs String Equality Rule](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#ES_COMPARING_STRINGS_WITH_EQ)
- [FindBugs Eclipse Plugin Guide](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/eclipse.html)

Other static analysis tools you might want to take a look at include [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) and [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3):

Use PMD or Findbugs plugins for eclipse to do this. These tools will also let you catch other common programming mistakes.

Direct link to findbug rule to detect this situation: http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#ES_COMPARING_STRINGS_WITH_EQ

Comment: Was just about to answer this. You could improve your answer with http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/eclipse.html#d0e1694 and http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#ES_COMPARING_STRINGS_WITH_EQ

Comment: THanks, I am aware of find bugs option, but wanted to catch these errors at compile time as opposed to another process.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can add checkstyle in eclipse which is able to display "==" for String as an error

Window -> Preferences -> Checkstyle ([download plug-in here](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/))

Then you can create a new Checkstyle.